# rails_admin show names of objects instead of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm trying to display visitors' names in my rails admin show page.
I'm doing it this way:

```
field :visitors
```

But I get displayed the following:

```
Visitor #7 and Visitor #8
```

I've tried to do something like this with pretty value:

```
configure :visitors do
  pretty_value do
    bindings[:object].visitors.each do |visitor|
      visitor.full_name
    end
  end
end
```

But it shows me objects' details:

```
[#<Visitor id: 7, first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", created_at: "2016-03-03 10:23:34", updated_at: "2016-03-03 10:23:34", booking_id: 7>, #<Visitor id: 8, first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Smith", created_at: "2016-03-03 10:23:34", updated_at: "2016-03-03 10:23:34", booking_id: 7>]
```

I simply want to display something like this:

```
John Smith and Bob Smith
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This link should be helpful   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658281/rails-admin-display-name-instead-of-id

Comment: @Udaykumardas, thanks for response. Yes, this link is quite good, I've checked it before. But it answers, how to display name for one object. And I have many objects/visitors.

Comment: Would changing the `object_label_method` for the `Visitor` class admin config help? (This is assuming you would want a `Visitor` object represented everywhere in your system with their `full_name`)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've found the solution using map:

```
bindings[:object].visitors.all.map {|v| v.full_name}.join(', ')
```

Comment: Yes, your fix is correct, `:each` returns the original array, not the resulting one.